# iPhone 4 Tab Bar Icons

Tags: iphone, icons, tabbar, retina-display

I'm having some issues getting high resolution tab bar icons displaying correctly for iPhone 4.  Basically I'm using the Apple guidelines of 96 x 64 for high resolution icons, but when I do this, my icon looks like it is being scaled many times in the tab bar icon area and only part of the icon appears.  If I set the icon size to 30 x 30, the icon displays correctly in terms of proportions but is not sharp because of the higher resolution of the iPhone 4 display.

I've tried other sizes like 64x64 and 60x60 but I get similar problems.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

you have to add @2x to youre iPhone 4 image..

So if you have a 30x30 image named image.png, make a 60x60 version and name it image@2x.png..

Comment: I saw this issue when I only had retina art. It seems that the tab bar expects both image sizes or it interprets the retina art as non-retina despite the @2x suffix.

Answer (score 4):

You have to name your icon file with @2x!
But in the attributes inspector you have to fulfill the field "Image" taking off the @2x on the file name:

example:
    Original file name:"icone@2x.png"
    Image field: "icone.png"